# Why can indexing a std::vector in a loop be faster than a raw pointer array on MSVC?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, visual-c++, stdvector

I was benchmarking Longest Common Subsequence algorithm implementation in C++ using a vector and a normal array and noticed a huge difference in performance of the versions. The new'd array was about 40% slower than `std::vector` in the compute part which I measure separately from the entire function itself. The for loops are identical themselves, yet they have a huge performance gap.

Here is the sample code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif

#define ARR2D(i, j, cols) ((i) * (cols) + (j))
typedef unsigned long long u64;
u64 timing = 0ull;

int LCS_Arr(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b)
{
    const int m = a.size() + 1;
    const int n = b.size() + 1;
    int *dp = new int[m * n];

    memset(dp, 0, m * n * sizeof(*dp));
    u64 tc;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&tc);
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])
                dp[ARR2D(i, j, n)] = dp[ARR2D(i - 1, j - 1, n)] + 1;
            else
                dp[ARR2D(i, j, n)] = std::max(dp[ARR2D(i - 1, j, n)], dp[ARR2D(i, j - 1, n)]);
        }
    const int result = dp[n * (m - 1) + n - 1];
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&timing);
    timing -= tc;

    delete[] dp;
    return result;
}

int LCS_VecLin(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b)
{
    const int m = a.size() + 1;
    const int n = b.size() + 1;
    std::vector<int> dp = std::vector<int>(m * n, 0);

    u64 tc;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&tc);
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])
                dp[ARR2D(i, j, n)] = dp[ARR2D(i - 1, j - 1, n)] + 1;
            else
                dp[ARR2D(i, j, n)] = std::max(dp[ARR2D(i - 1, j, n)], dp[ARR2D(i, j - 1, n)]);
        }
    const int result = dp[n * (m - 1) + n - 1];
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&timing);
    timing -= tc;

    return result;
}

void main()
{
    srand(576);
    constexpr int Length = 30000;
    std::vector<int> a(Length), b(Length);

    std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), [] { return rand() % 256; });
    std::generate(b.begin(), b.end(), [] { return rand() % 256; });

    u64 t0, t1, f;
    u64 d0, d1, f0, f1;
    int res0, res1;


    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&f);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&t0);
    res1 = LCS_VecLin(a, b);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&t1);
    d1 = t1 - t0;
    f1 = timing;

    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&t0);
    res0 = LCS_Arr(a, b);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&t1);
    d0 = t1 - t0;
    f0 = timing;

    double fm = 1.0 / f;
    printf("Array:  %d - Time taken Arr: %.3f s\n", res0, fm * d0);
    printf("VecLin: %d - Time taken Vec: %.3f s\n", res1, fm * d1);
    printf("ArrCompute: %.3f s\n", f0 * fm);
    printf("VecCompute: %.3f s\n", f1 * fm);
}
```

This is the output I usually get:

```
Array:  3493 - Time taken Arr: 1.373 s
VecLin: 3493 - Time taken Vec: 0.877 s
ArrCompute: 1.085 s
VecCompute: 0.612 s
```

Does anyone have any reasonable explanation on why this happens? GCC and Clang exhibit no such issues and yield about the same level of performance on both versions. Extracting the computation loop into a separate function leads to better performance and matches the `std::vector` when used with either container.

I tried both implementations, I expected them to yield about the same performance when compiled with optimizations on, but the `std::vector` implementation turned out much faster.

Comment: Have you seen the assembly difference? [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d81P64q8T)

Comment: Which optimization settings have you enabled? If you swap the function calls, does the result change?

Comment: `std::vector<int> dp = std::vector<int>(m * n, 0);` --> `std::vector<int> dp(m * n);`

Comment: `int *dp = new int[m * n];

    memset(dp, 0, m * n * sizeof(*dp));` --> `int *dp = new int[m * n]{};`

Comment: `#define ARR2D(i, j, cols)` --> `inline int ARR2D(int i, int j, int cols)`

Comment: @273K I'm using /O2 /Ot /GL /GS- /arch:AVX2 /LTCG, basically all the optimizations offered. Also, reordering the function calls makes a very small difference.

Comment: I see `/DNDEBUG` is missing.

Comment: NDEBUG is defined in preprocessor definitions.
Doing all the changes mentioned here in the comments also changed nothing.

Comment: Running that code, with the optimizations you specified, I get vector being slower by about 0.1 seconds.

Comment: @SPACoD I get approximately the same results as ChrisMM when running the code using Visual C++ 2022, release mode.  You *are* running a 64-bit application, right?  A 32-bit application would have serious issues with multiplying `m * n` if both `m` and `n` are 30000.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's really strange, I am using x64 Release mode. I created a brand new project, enabled /sdl-, /Qpar and /arch:AVX512 along with already mentioned switches and still getting about the same results. Also using VC++ 2022.

Comment: This is just matter of order. If you switch order it then `LCS_VecLin` will win.  So simply cache miss result. Writing good performance test is hard and full of subtle traps. So be careful. I would recommend to use google benchmark.

Comment: @MarekR It doesn't work like that though, reordering doesn't make it 400 ms faster, it makes it maybe 20-50 ms faster.

Comment: On my machine I got exactly opposite results after changing order.

Comment: Maybe run these as completely separate programs.  That will remove any "one affecting the other" issues.

Comment: Interesting problem!  I pulled the heavy-lifting for loops out into a separate function I called `work`, and then the vector (5.875s) was faster than the array (6.125s).  (Difference is probably hot cache related.)  Perhaps the compiler is able to do some loop unrolling with the array case, but unable with the vector case.  I haven't peeked at the generated assembly.

Comment: @Jason I tried compiling separately, excluding the vector or array code using the preprocessor and I still get the same result.